# XCode keep on logging 'Returning connectedAccessories count 0'

Tags: ios, xcode, logging

Xcode version: 13.4.1
My app has connected with Bluetooth. But Xcode keeps on logging 'Returning connectedAccessories count 0' when debugging.
How can I stop the log by changing some settings? Because it is really annoying.